# Производительность маршрутизатора

Tags: vpn, маршрутизация, linux

*Предистория:*
Инет подключается так: комп к локалке, в локалке сервак до которого **vpn**-подключение и готово.

*История:*Есть **D-Link**'овское чудо техники (DIR-320) которое из-за своих проблем с производительностью режет скорость при vpn до 0.7/0.7 mbps (хотя напрямую с компом где-то 4/6 mbps). Эта чудомашина нужна для того чтобы вафля (Wi-Fi) был и раздача инета ethernet кабелем на несколько компов (обычно их два). Так вот, реально ли как-то решить эту проблему? И как?

*Небольшое дополнение:*
Имеется **старая-старая-старая** машинка которая пылиться в шкафу. Может поставить на неё фряху (FreeBSD) или что-то подобное, установить вторую сетевуху и заставить по одной получать инет по **vpn**, а по второй раздавать уже без какого-либо шифрования. Прокатит ли?

Comment: vpn != encryption

Comment: А без VPN что-то из (Ethernet и WiFi) пропадает?

Comment: Без vpn интернет отсутсвует... и остаётся только локальная сеть провайдера

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте перешить D-Link на DD-WRT например. Если не решит проблему, то смотрите в сторону старая-старая-старая машинка, но не все сетевые карты одинаково полезны. Думаю, что двадцатку Вы получите.